# How to filer emails from me to me, or, alternatively, all the others?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I asked [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121005/how-to-actually-archive-messages-automatically-so-that-they-not-show-up-in-othe) about email from "me" showing up in the list of email in Gmail. I think after further tests that there is no direct solution.

I worked up an alternative approach but I am missing one use case.

As a reminder of the problem: whenever I send an email, it shows up in the `Other Messages` list, right below the `Important and unread` ones. I believe this behaviour is incorrect as only emails I received should be listed (apparently Google this otherwise, but never mind).

*I therefore created a filter which immediately archives emails from "me" (so sent from my email address). This works great, no more sent emails in that list.*

There is one use case which is not covered though: I sometimes send emails from myself to myself as reminders, links to read, etc. These emails are also (correctly) caught by the filter and therefore the whole idea of sending emails to myself dies.

There are two solutions (filters) to this problem:

- filter all emails from me and **not** to me and archive them
- keep my current filter and make another one to filter all emails "from me and to me" and send them (back?) to the inbox

Problem with solution #1: I do not know how to negate an email address ("everything but xx@yy.com")

Problem with solution #2: I do not know how to move such a filtered message to Infobox (I do not see such a feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From me, but not to me, enter in search box:

```
from:me -to:me
```

**Notes:**

If you have conversations turned on (default), this will find any thread where there exists at least one email you sent but did not copy yourself. Go to `Gmail > Settings > Conversation View => Turn off` to change this behavior. With conversations off, GMail will find single messages that meet your criteria, but your emails will no longer be threaded into conversations.

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much, this is what I was looking for (and also learned that "me" means all my addresses)